# displaying an html element depending on other state in angular

Tags: angular

I have an unordered list as below. So I need to show number 2 list item if only item 1 displays.

```
    <li nz-menu-item (click)="downloadInvoiceDocument(data.id,'ENVELOPE')">Zarf indir</li>
    <li nz-menu-divider></li>
1.  <li nz-menu-item (click)="saveInvoice(data.id)">Kaydet</li>
2.  <li nz-menu-divider ></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<ng-container/>` to wrap elements and apply `*ngIf` to the container, as followings

```
<li nz-menu-item (click)="downloadInvoiceDocument(data.id,'ENVELOPE')">Zarf indir</li>
<li nz-menu-divider></li>
<ng-container *ngIf="data.id"> <!-- or any other condition you want to apply -->
    <li nz-menu-item (click)="saveInvoice(data.id)">Kaydet</li>
    <li nz-menu-divider ></li>
</ng-container>
```